# Why does my Windows system service which saves running application names to a text file not create the file?

Tags: c#, .net, io, windows-services

I have to write a system service which allows me save to a text file the names of running applications every minute.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)60).TotalMilliseconds); //Every minute
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(your_method);
    t.Start();   
}

private static void your_method(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
    {
        string s = " Process:  " + theprocess.ProcessName;
        File.AppendAllText("RunningAplications.txt", s);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way? (I don't think so because that doesn't create a file.) How can I create a system service from this?

Comment: `new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)60).TotalMilliseconds);`  -> that is an hour. You need `new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);` to have a tick every minute. So run it and wait a minute.

Comment: I changed to 1 and waited and file still doesnt exist.

Comment: Where are you  looking for that file? Give it a full path, eg `File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\RunningAplications.txt", s);`

Comment: I think smth is wrong bcs when i add Console.WriteLine(s); that dont even print me anything after 1 minute. Ofc i tried add full path still doesnt work.

Comment: Put breakpoint in `your_method()` and run debug - does program stop there after 1 minute?

Comment: Well I have used your code in a simple console app and it works. Try debugging it by setting a breakpoint at the event handler.

Comment: I think smth is wrong with that method bcs when i try it in main it works but i dont how use debug ;/

Comment: *but i dont how use debug.* No problem, that can be fixed... a starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx another worthy read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
}

private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    //I have tried this and it wrote my name.
    System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\report.txt", true);
    SaveFile.WriteLine("saumil");
    SaveFile.Flush();
    SaveFile.Close();

    ////Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
    ////foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
    ////{
    ////    string s = " Process:  " + theprocess.ProcessName;
    ////    SaveFile.WriteLine("saumil");
    ////    SaveFile.Flush();
    ////    SaveFile.Close();
    ////    //SaveFile.WriteLine(s);
    ////}
}
```

Comment: Still the same something doesnt work i mean nothin is saved to file.